# How to join a string and float value in a calculated field using Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to create a calculated field where the output is "x% Over the Goal", however cannot due to string and float values. Essentially, what I want is the following:

```
IF Actuals > Goal THEN Actuals/Goal+'Over Goal'
ELSEIF  Actuals < Goal then Actuals/Goal+'Under Goal'
ELSE 'At Goal' END
```

Is something like this possible? I've tried creating two separate calculated fields and concatenating them, but that does not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You Can achieve this in a single calculated field:

```
IF [Actuals] > [Goal] THEN STR(FLOAT([Actuals] / [Goal])) + "Over Goal"
ELSEIF [Actuals] < [Goal] THEN STR(FLOAT([Actuals] / [Goal])) + "Under Goal"  
ELSE "At Goal" END
```